# Log full of [Note] InnoDB: ft_end() after upgrade to MariaDB 10.3.10

Tags: innodb, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

My upgrade path was `MariaDB 10.2.18` to `MariaDB 10.3.10`.

There are no bugs reported on mariadb or mysql bug tracker (at least that I could find).

`...
Oct 24 17:45:33 host1 mysqld[12196]: 2018-10-24 17:45:33 173491 [Note] InnoDB: ft_end()
Oct 24 17:45:33 host1 mysqld[12196]: 2018-10-24 17:45:33 173491 [Note] InnoDB: ft_end()
Oct 24 17:45:33 host1 mysqld[12196]: 2018-10-24 17:45:33 173491 [Note] InnoDB: ft_end()
Oct 24 17:45:33 host1 mysqld[12196]: 2018-10-24 17:45:33 173491 [Note] InnoDB: ft_end()
Oct 24 17:45:39 host1 mysqld[12196]: 2018-10-24 17:45:39 173494 [Note] InnoDB: ft_end()
Oct 24 17:45:39 host1 mysqld[12196]: 2018-10-24 17:45:39 173494 [Note] InnoDB: ft_end()
Oct 24 17:45:39 host1 mysqld[12196]: 2018-10-24 17:45:39 173494 [Note] InnoDB: ft_end()
Oct 24 17:45:39 host1 mysqld[12196]: 2018-10-24 17:45:39 173494 [Note] InnoDB: ft_end()
Oct 24 17:46:58 host1 mysqld[12196]: 2018-10-24 17:46:58 173517 [Note] InnoDB: ft_end()
Oct 24 17:46:58 host1 mysqld[12196]: 2018-10-24 17:46:58 173517 [Note] InnoDB: ft_end()
Oct 24 17:46:58 host1 mysqld[12196]: 2018-10-24 17:46:58 173517 [Note] InnoDB: ft_end()
Oct 24 17:46:58 host1 mysqld[12196]: 2018-10-24 17:46:58 173517 [Note] InnoDB: ft_end()
Oct 24 17:47:04 host1 mysqld[12196]: 2018-10-24 17:47:04 173518 [Note] InnoDB: ft_end()
...`

Enviroment:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- MariaDB from MariaDB repo (not Ubuntu ones)
- mysql_upgrade has been run with success

I found one reference online but no answers:

- https://xenforo.com/community/threads/mariadb-innodb-ft_end.149080/

Comment: Do you have found out any application error during run time. It's seems like that only the log message.

Comment: Application runs OK - no error detected so far. But logging multiple times per second only in 10.3 - seems strange.

Comment: Which OS is this? If CentOS/RHEL/Fedora or derivatives, have you run the  `mysql_upgrade` command after upgrading?

Comment: @dbdemon Ubuntu 16.04 LTS . `mysql_upgrade` has been executed after upgrade.

Comment: It looks like a debug message the developers forgot to remove before release. Do you have any 'unusual' storage engines or plugins installed?

Comment: @dbdemon No. Default install. We use only InnoDB on that server.

Comment: What's your [`log_warnings`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#log_warnings) setting? The default should be 1.

Comment: `log_warnings=2` . But default value is: `2 (>= MariaDB 10.2.4)` `1 (<= MariaDB 10.2.3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported it https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17624

They reacted fast. It seems this will be resolved with this pull request
https://github.com/MariaDB/server/pull/916
https://github.com/MariaDB/server/pull/916/commits/9997f860f618851def580cbd34a192e842cd6ef4

It was only a developer info message.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a [rather meaningless](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.3/storage/innobase/handler/ha_innodb.cc#L10120) info message. It certainly isn't an error or something to worry about.

It is a bit noisy and goes against a principle of the error log being quite clean (and meaningful). I recommend submitting a bug/pr to remove this line of code.

Comment: These were my thoughts exactly but wanted to check anyway.